# Find xml node whose name is a concatenation of attribute of another node and string constant

Tags: xpath

I have a bit of a tough xpath query (which I'm not entirely sure can be done).

I have the below xml

```
<Root>
    <PersonOne Name='jon'/>
    <PersonTwo Name='bob'/>
    <JonDetails>some text</JonDetails>
    <BobDetails>some details about Bob</BobDetails>
</Root>
```

I know it is a bit of a contrived example but the xml structure I am dealing with is fixed and I cannot change it.

Basically I'm trying to figure out the xpath to select the *Detail node for the name attribute in the PersonOne node.

So to do this I need to concat the atribute value of 'Name' in the PersonOne node with the constant Details to get 'JonDetails' as a node name.

I have this so far but it doesn't work but I think it is along the right lines.

```
/Root/*[contains(name(), concat(/Root/PersonOne/@Name, 'Details'))]
```

However, just to add to the fun it has to be a case insensitive match on the node name.  I know this can be done with a translate function.

Any pointers in the right direction?

Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

will this expression be better?

```
/Root/*[translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = translate(concat(/Root/PersonOne/@Name, 'details'), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')]
```

it looks for an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out! It's not too pretty but it works.

```
/Root/*[contains(translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), translate(concat(/Root/PersonOne/@Name, 'details'), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))]
```

If anyone can improve on this it would be good to see how.

Thanks